# Swift xcode errors: Could not infer type for 'shape' and enum case not found in error type

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to create a drawing method inside xcode in order to draw different shapes inside a UIView. The purpose of this app is to attach the drawing to a row that is saved in a table (I will post the table code if needed but I don't think it is necessary for this error).

Screenshot of error:

[image]

```
import UIKit



/*

    This program is for Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2

*/





class CanvasView: UIView {

    enum ShapeType: String

    {

        case Line = "Line"

        case Ellipse = "Ellipse"

        case Rectangle = "Rectangle"

        case FilledEllipse = "Filled Ellipse"

        case FilledRectangle = "Filled Rectangle"

        case Scribble = "Scribble"

    }



    var shape: ShapeType = .Line

    var color: UIColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    var first :CGPoint = CGPointZero

    var last  :CGPoint = CGPointZero

    var points: [CGPoint] = []



    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.

    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        // Drawing code

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)



        let rect = CGRect(x: first.x, y: first.y, width: last.x - first.x, height: last.y - first.y)

        switch shape {

        case .Line:

            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, first.x, first.y)

            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, last.x, last.y)

            CGContextStrokePath(context)

        case .Ellipse:

            CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, rect)

        case .Rectangle:

            CGContextStrokeRect(context, rect)

        case .FilledEllipse:

            CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect)

        case .FilledRectangle:

            CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        case .Scribble:

            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, first.x, first.y)

            for p in points {

                CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, p.x, p.y)

            }

            CGContextStrokePath(context)

        }

    }



    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first {

            first = touch.locationInView(self)

            last = first

            points.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            if shape == .Scribble {

                points.append(first)

            }

            setNeedsDisplay()

        }

    }



    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first {

            last = touch.locationInView(self)

            if shape == .Scribble {

                points.append(last)

            }

            setNeedsDisplay()

        }

    }



    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first {

            last = touch.locationInView(self)

            if shape == .Scribble {

                points.append(last)

            }

            setNeedsDisplay()

        }

    }



    override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    }



}
```

Comment: Something else weird is happening. None of the errors match the code their pointing at. Try restarting Xcode or doing a clean and build (in the menus Product > Clean)

Comment: Or, if "clean" doesn't do it, locate the "derived data" folder (Xcode "Preferences" - "Locations"), quit Xcode, empty the "derived data" folder, and then restart Xcode.

Comment: `This program is for Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2` Also, try updating Xcode.

Comment: @nhgrif - I agree, but I tested this in Xcode 6.3 and it worked fine (other than the signatures for touches methods are not right).